# php mysql updating IP address cannot work right

Tags: php, mysql, ip

The code is used to update the IP address user logged in. When I print the $sql string, it seems it is correct, the IP address is 1886883852, but after updated to mysql, the value is 2149463110. I have tried to set the data type in mysql as INT(11) bigint(12), all the same.
If I try to write a string as

```
UPDATE ddns SET LastIP=1886883852, LastUpdate=now() WHERE ID=1
```

directly, without using any variable, it works correctly.

Really cannot understand. Anybody can help?

```
//get dns
function getIP(){
        //check the current ip address registered
        //Test if it is a shared client
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
          $ipaddr=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        //Is it a proxy address
        }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
          $ipaddr=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }else{
          $ipaddr=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        $ipaddr = ip2long($ipaddr);
        return $ipaddr;
}

$ipaddr = getIP();
$sql = "UPDATE ddns SET LastIP=$ipaddr, LastUpdate=now() WHERE ID=1";
echo $sql; **//here UPDATE ddns SET LastIP=1886883852, LastUpdate=now() WHERE ID=1**
$result = mysqli_query($dbh,$sql) or die("Query failed:");
**//Here after updated, the value of ipaddr in database is 2149463110**
if ($result)
        echo "Update ddns successfully";
else
        echo "faild to update ddns";
```

Comment: Why are you interpolating variables instead of using a prepared statement? Isn't that one of the main benefits of mysqli over mysql?

Comment: No matter how I approach this problem it just should not be happening. The only thing I can think of to change would be to move to a prepared statement like @Barmar suggests.

Comment: Thanks both. prepared statement seems have problem with mysqli. The problems solved after I changed a editor from vi. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the reason. When I use **Chrome** to visit and update, the database will write 2149463110, when I use **firefox or safari**, the result will be 1886883852. 
Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way:

```
$sql = "UPDATE ddns SET LastIP='$ipaddr', LastUpdate=now() WHERE ID=1";
```

The IP address appears to be a string, so it needs to be quoted. Or you can  var_dump the $_SERVER superglobal in order to check the field type. Or exceeding the limit of the memory.

Just for a testing case, you can change the field type to float, varchar or even text.

Comment: LastIP is int, not string. Actually at first I used string, it is strange too, the same problem. When print the $sql, it is correct, has my IP. but after updated, it is another IP, in string.

Comment: I'm very out of ideas, but still I have some thoughts. I see you are always updating the ID=1. So anyone who can access your application, will update with its IP. So, maybe, you have a bot, which is constantly accessing your application and reupdates your IP for ID=1. If also could be a inner bot, if you have uploaded your application to a hosting.