# Updating IP address in Mysql resulted different when using Chrome and Firefox

Tags: php, mysql, browser, ip-address

This question refers to [php mysql updating IP address cannot work right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017692/php-mysql-updating-ip-address-cannot-work-right)
Post here hope to get an answer.
The following code update visitors IP address in database. But when tested using Chrome, the result is wired.

### The output is

string(119) "UPDATE ddns SET LastIP=1886947462, LastUpdate=now() WHERE ddns_name='kc001'

string(112) "select INET_NTOA(LastIP) as IPADDR FROM ddns where ddns_name='kc001'
112.120.136.134

---

But when check Mysql, the LastIP in database is actually 2149463110. The second query also give my correct IP address. But when query in other files, the IP got will be 128.30.52.70

When using Firefox or Safari, LastIp in database will be 1886947462, correct.

Any explanation?

```
<?php
$dbh = mysql_connect("..mydatabase info..") or die("I cannot connect to the database");
mysql_select_db("glddns");
function getIP(){

    //Test if it is a shared client
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
        $ip_tmp=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    //Is it a proxy address
    }elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        $ip_tmp=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $ip_tmp=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    //The value of $ip at this point would look something like: "192.0.34.166"
    $ip = ip2long($ip_tmp);
    return $ip;
}
function getddns(){
        $var = explode(".",$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
        return $var[0];
}
$ipaddr = getIP();
$ddns = $_GET["ddns"];

$sql = sprintf("UPDATE ddns SET LastIP=%u, LastUpdate=now() WHERE ddns_name='%s'",$ipaddr,$ddns);
var_dump($sql);
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed:".mysql_error());
if ($result && mysql_affected_rows()==1)
    echo "Update Done";
else
    echo "Update Failed";

$sql= sprintf("select INET_NTOA(LastIP) as IPADDR FROM ddns where ddns_name='%s'",$ddns);

echo "<br><br>";
var_dump($sql);
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed:".mysql_error());
while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo "<br>". $line["IPADDR"];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($dbh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very strange thing. It happens on my chrome before. Now the problem doesn't exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if either of your browsers is set to use a (different) proxy server.

Comment: I checked. both no proxy server used. Even when both use proxy server, yield the same results.